# How to remove Connect With Us block in footer

Tags: blocks, magento-1

I want to remove the Connect With Us block from footer using local.xml. How can this be done? I know how to remove the other blocks from footer using:

```
<reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer_links"/>
        <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        <remove name="cms_footer_links"/>
    </reference>
```

Also how can I remove the block containing

> © 2014 Madison Island. All Rights Reserved

using local.xml?
  Basically I just want my footer to contain the ABOUT US column.
  All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily remove copyright text from magento admin web footer section.